# sonarQube displaying code coverage 0% in scala

Tags: scala, sonarqube, sbt

i am using `sonarQube-8.5.1.38104` and i am using it in my scala project and followed this [link](https://sonar-scala.com/docs/setup/sbt-sonar/)
here is my `plugins.sbt` file

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.6.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mwz" % "sbt-sonar" % "2.2.0")
```

and here is my `build.sbt` file

```
import sbtsonar.SonarPlugin.autoImport.sonarUseExternalConfig

coverageEnabled := true

sonarProperties ++= Map(
  "sonar.host.url" -> "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
  "sonar.projectName" -> "myproject-backend",
  "sonar.projectKey" -> "sonar-myproject-backend",
  "sonar.sources" -> "src/main/scala-2.13",
  "sonar.tests" -> "src/test/scala-2.13",
  "sonar.junit.reportPaths" -> "target/test-reports",
  "sonar.sourceEncoding" -> "UTF-8",
  "sonar.scala.scoverage.reportPath"->"target/scala-2.13/scoverage-report/scoverage.xml",
  "sonar.scala.scapegoat.reportPath" -> "target/scala-2.13/scapegoat-report/scapegoat.xml"
)
```

followed [sbt-scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage)

then i did
-> `sbt` -> `coverage` -> `test` -> `coverageReport`
generated the report

```
[info] Written Cobertura report [/home/user/git/myproject/target/scala-2.13/coverage-report/cobertura.xml]
[info] Written XML coverage report [/home/user/git/myproject/target/scala-2.13/scoverage-report/scoverage.xml]
[info] Written HTML coverage report [/home/user/git/myproject/target/scala-2.13/scoverage-report/index.html]
[info] Statement coverage.: 38.67%
[info] Branch coverage....: 31.58%
```

then i did

> `sonarScan`

and check the report at http://127.0.0.1:9000/dashboard?id=myproject-backend

then **code coverage** is displayed **0.0%** and **Unit tests -**

and i have checked the reports exists at

```
target/scala-2.13/scoverage-report/scoverage.xml
target/scala-2.13/scapegoat-report/scapegoat.xml
```

and class test reports exists at

```
target/test-reports

com.myproject.test.abctest.EventTest.xml               com.myproject.test.xyztest.FileUploadTest.xml  TEST-com.myproject.test.xyztest.DirectoryCreationTest.xml
com.myproject.test.abctest.QueryEventTest.xml                TEST-com.myproject.test.abctest.InsertEventTest.xml   TEST-com.myproject.test.xyztest.FileUploadTest.xml
com.myproject.test.xyztest.DirectoryCreationTest.xml  TEST-com.myproject.test.abctest.QueryEventTest.xml
```

why i am getting code coverage 0% then ? what am i missing here ? please guide ,thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was giving the wrong key
the correct key was

```
"sonar.scala.coverage.reportPaths"->"target/scala-2.13/scoverage-report/scoverage.xml",
"sonar.scala.scapegoat.reportPaths" -> "target/scala-2.13/scapegoat-report/scapegoat-scalastyle.xml"
```

after that I am able to get the code coverage % but unit tests count was still missing because I think its not supported by sonar right now here scala is not mentioned in test execution
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @swaheed,
I can't add a comment to your post due to reputation limit.

We also come across this problem when using sonar-scala. We found that the code coverage can be showed with the below properties:

For SonarQube Version 8.6: needs to use **sonar.scala.coverage.reportPaths** as @swaheed mentioned.

> "sonar.scala.coverage.reportPaths"->"target/scala-2.13/scoverage-report/scoverage.xml"

For SonarQube Version 8.7.1 Community (I follow this docker-compose to bring up the SonarQubeDocker https://github.com/sonar-scala/sonar-scala-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml), either of the properties below works

> "sonar.scala.coverage.reportPaths"->"target/scala-2.13/scoverage-report/scoverage.xml"

or

> "sonar.scala.scoverage.reportPath"->"target/scala-2.13/scoverage-report/scoverage.xml"

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation surrounding `sonar.scala.scoverage.reportPath` can you provide a link?

Comment: @swaheed, the config key is mentioned here https://sonar-scala.com/docs/setup/sbt-sonar/#usage